# AWS S3 uploading hidden files by default

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have created a bucket in AWS and a couple of IAM. The IAM by default are included in a group with read-only access. However, when I create my bucket I generated a policy to grant access to specific IAM to **list**, **put** and **get**. Now I'm trying to run a simple command to put a file with one of these AWS IAM from my site:

```
aws s3api put-object --bucket <bucket name>  --key poc/test.txt  --body <windows path file>
```

The output is successful, means that the files are always loaded. However, when I take a look the bucket in AWS I have to click on **show** because all loadings are setting the bucket content as hidden.

[image]

The account that I'm using to verify the files uploaded in AWS has manager access in S3 and I'm going thru the web console. How should I load the files without the hidden mark?

thanks

Comment: versioning is enabled in your bucket. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/view-object-versions.html.... the file upload is successful as you see the file in the console, are you looking any specific details?

Comment: yes versioning is enable. I want to know why when I explore the bucket with a manager user thru the web console I have to click in show to see the files rather than look them up automatically. thanks

Comment: it's by design, it would show the latest version by default. you would need to click show to see versions.

Comment: So by design AWS will hide all files loaded by an IAM when I use versioning?

Comment: Yes, if `Versioning` is enabled, the console is designed to show  the latest version of particular file, unless you click on `Show` option. Similarly, when you call `get-object` API call, you will get the latest version of file. To be able to retrieve specific version, you must add `--version-id` parameter with desired version identifier